# why is my OnCollisionStay is not calling?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

[image]I am very new to unity, i have used onCollitionStay() method but its not doing anything, i wanted to do in my code is "if zombie stays for 20 seconds with player the player life should be reduced", could anyone can help me out with this? 
my code is

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo) {
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "zombie") {
        transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        dieTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if(dieTime>20.0){
            noOfLivesLeft--;
            if(noOfLivesLeft<=0){
                transform.localScale = new Vector2(0,0);
                Application.LoadLevel ("GameOver");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The usual cause of this is using 2D colliders with 3D physics functions or vice versa. Can you show us the collider setup used on your player and zombie?

Comment: i hv uploaded one of my inspection windows, for all characters i have used boxColliders only thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using 2D colliders and Rigidbodies, but 3D collision functions

Switch to using [OnCollisionStay**2D**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay2D.html)(Collision**2D** collision) to respond to 2D collisions.

Comment: Thanks man, It's silly mistake i didn't read API Thankyou very much to helping me out.

Comment: Don't sweat it. We get one of these every week. ;) This, unassigned references, and mixed-up prefab instantiation are probably the three most common "oh of course!" errors in Unity. ;)